# I want to put tickers in brackets

Tags: python

I want to put AEM into brackets, so that text will look like: Agnico Eagle Mines Limited (AEM)

```
text = "Agnico Eagle Mines Limited AEM"
def add_brackets(test):
     for word in test:
         if word.isupper():
             word = "(" + word + ")"
     print(test)

print(add_brackets(text))
```

What's wrong with the code? I get the original text.

Comment: You haven't changed 'test' so it will always print the original string. When you loop through and change word, that change is not automatically reflected in the original string.

Comment: You need to `return` something...

Answer (score 1):

Two things, 1 you are checking per character, not per word. 2 you are not modifying `text` you are just setting `word` and not doing anything with it.

```
text = "Agnico Eagle Mines Limited AEM"


def add_brackets(test):
    outstr = ""
    for word in test.split(" "):
        if word.isupper():
            outstr += " (" + word + ")"
        else:
            outstr += " " + word
    return outstr.strip()


print(add_brackets(text))
```

Edit: Fancier

```
text = "Agnico Eagle Mines Limited AEM"


def add_brackets(test):
    return " ".join(["({})".format(word) if word.isupper() else word for word in test.split(" ")])

print(add_brackets(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be pretty concise with a regular expression substitution:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Agnico Eagle Mines Limited AEM"
>>> re.sub(r'\b([A-Z]+)\b', r'(\1)', text)
'Agnico Eagle Mines Limited (AEM)'
```

This looks for multiple uppercase characters together, with word boundaries (like whitespace) on either side, then substitutes that matched group with the same text (the `\1`) with the addition of parentheses.

In a function:

```
>>> import re
>>> def add_brackets(s):
...     return re.sub(r'\b([A-Z]+)\b', r'(\1)', s)
...
>>> print(add_brackets(text))
Agnico Eagle Mines Limited (AEM)
```